# Creating NativeScript Plugin using iOS SDK results in 'Undefined symbols for architecture' errors

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I am trying to create a NativeScript plugin in order to integrate an iOS SDK of a bluetooth printer to a NativeScript application.

Here is the link to the [SDK as Static Framework](https://my.pcloud.com/publink/show?code=XZgwYa7ZLp3JFoJSiRSmjEnSiBalDRUP3h3X)

I keep getting the following error with the `army7` part showing different values after fresh install of the plugin.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey", referenced from:
      -[RTBleService startScan:serviceArray:clear:] in RTPrinterSDK(RTBleService.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CBCentralManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RTPrinterSDK(RTBleService.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CBUUID", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RTPrinterSDK(RTBleService.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description
```

In addition to trying to use the official plugin seed plugin, I have ultimately done the following which according to my research should have been enough:

**INSTALLATION:**

1) Created a folder for the plugin files within the /app directory (this plugin is only intended for this project at present). This folder has the following structure:

```
/app/plugin/src/package.json   
/app/plugin/src/platforms/ios/RTPrinterSDK.framework
```

The RTPrinterSDK.framework has two folders, *Headers* (has *.h* files) and *Modules* (has the *module.modulemap* file) in addition to two files being *Info.plist* and *RTPrinterSDK.a*.

2) I have added the plugin to the project by running `tns plugin add app/plugin/src`

3) I believe now `tns run ios --bundle` should run the project on the connected device with the plugin - albeit I have not done anything with the plugin yet on the application.

**SANITY CHECKS:**

1) `lipo -info app/plugin/src/platforms/ios/RTPrinterSDK.framework/RTPrinterSDK` displays that the `Architectures in the fat file: /path-to-RTPrinterSDK are: army7 i386 x64_64 arm64`.

2) `tns run ios --bundle` without the custom plugin works both in emulators and real device

3) just in case, I have also attempted this on a fresh new `--ts` project

4) there is a demo application that comes with the SDK. Whilst it is not a NativeScript application, it is an Xcode project file and I was able to successfully run it on the same connected device.

There is a note in the SDK referring to a `ble_serial.plist` file. As per the instructions, I am confident that I need to integrate this to somewhere within the plugin folder to access bluetooth connectivity but I am not sure where. Given that the errors are referring to modules with `"Ble"` in the name, I fear there might be a connection.

Please note that I did not write/prepare the SDK. The vendor of the printer provided it. I only have access to it as it is provided.

I would hugely appreciate any tips or feedback regarding this issue.

Comment: I guess you are using a custom framework, have you compiled it as universal?

Comment: @Manoj it sounds like OP doesn't have the original source code; a vendor provided this SDK as-is and that's all we have to work with.

Comment: I am afraid @JamieBirch is right as it is also highlighted in the question. _Please note that I did not write/prepare the SDK. The vendor of the printer provided it. I only have access to it as it is provided._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following valuable advice from the NativeScript community, I discovered that the `CB` prefix in the errors refer to `CoreBluetooth`.

In order to ensure that it is loaded I ended up creating a new file at `/app/plugin/src/platforms/ios/build.xcconfig` and adding the following line to it:

`OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -framework "CoreBluetooth"`.

It compiles and runs on device now.